# How to upload a file folder but not file using html?

Tags: html, upload, directory

What html control should be used to upload a folder but not a file ? Or is there any method to upload a folder (not be compressed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can with [webkitdirectory](http://sapphion.com/2011/11/html5-folder-upload-with-webkitdirectory/) but not supported in all browsers yet:

```
<input name="file_input[]" id="file_input" multiple="" webkitdirectory="" type="file">
```

Comment: Yeah,I know thi.Is there any method to support other browsers?

Comment: If you asking for html, that is HTML5 which newest for now. You can use flash, java, or another plugin. There is no another html syntax for now.